# Get/catch response status in a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint

I have a promise where it sometimes gives an error (400 and 403, depending on the user) response, depending on the user). I want to try to catch the response,do a conditional (if) so I can depending on the server response, do a different function.

It looks like:

```
let item = pnp.sp.web.lists
   .getById(Constants.eventCalendarGuid)
   .items
   .getById(this.props.item.ID);

item.attachmentFiles.add("file2.txt", "Here is my content")
   .then(v => console.log(v));
```

I have tried to do a then chain and  ==> catch => error but can't get the response code at all.

Comment: can you show the code in server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample demo:

```
item.attachmentFiles.add("file2.txt", "Here is my content")
   .then(v => console.log(v))
   .catch((err) =>{
     if(err.status==400)
      console.log(err.status);
    else
      console.log(err.status);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use the [catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) function

```
item.attachmentFiles.add("file2.txt", "Here is my content")
  .then(v => console.log(v))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: I did try that, but I get a full message and not a status code. Ie. not usable in a conditional.